# how to get put request working in angular using a rest API

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Im working on my own project, its a game library, I have a separate file with my hard coded data in where each item has an Id and a name. The problem im having is my component.ts file cannot see the value of id, even though my get request works perfectly fine and displays the id and the name in a table. Im following a tutorial but adapting it so it works for mine however this causes issues when I cant ask for help on my specific problems.

I have tried changing variable names incase I messed something up that way but that didn't do it so im not sure what else to do to be honest.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let game of games">
    <button (click)="updateGame($game)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Update</button>
    <td>{{game.id}}</td>
    <td>{{game.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
export class UpdateGameBodyComponent {
  public games: any = [];

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/api/games').subscribe(response => {
      this.games = response;
    });
  }

  updateGame(game) {

    this.httpClient.put('http://localhost:3000/api/games' + '/' + game.id, JSON.stringify({
        isRead: true
      }))
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
  }
};
```

When I click the update button the console displays an error saying it cannot get the value of Id, i would like to fix that issue so that i can continue making the put request work.

Answer (score 1):

Change '$game' to 'game' in HTML because *ngFor returns the value not the DOM event

```
<button (click)="updateGame(game)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Update</button>
```

Comment: This seems to be part of your problem, although you're describing it a bit differently. Are you able to see the `game.id` in your HTML or not? I couldn't completely gather from your initial question @sammyleighg.

Comment: when i remove the $ symbol, clicking the update button does nothing.

yes it can see the game.id in the html file but not in the TS file

Comment: @Bjorn 'Bjeaurn' S

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fbgb9m I reproduced your issue using mock API. solution what I suggested working fine. can you share the console.log(game) in updateGame Method

Comment: its almost like its not going into the function, as nothing is being logged in the console. not an error or anything, its literally like the button does nothing.